# How to find out empty files from a bunch of excels, pdf files in a folder?

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, pdf

I download some pdfs and csv files from my server and many times the files are empty. I have to check manually all those files. Generally I get 80-90 files in a day and I am planning to write a python script for it.

I have tried below code. Please find it below:

```
import os
os.stat("Book1").st_size == 0
```

but since the size of an empty excel file is also 8 KB this isn't working.
Also it will be different case for pdf files.

I want to get all names of the blank files in a new txt file.

Comment: Also, making the .st_size==8 kb something won't be Ok since I think it isn't fixed.

Comment: Do the empty spreadsheets contain anything? e.g. a header  Or no cells at all?